# Ignore from TFS but include in project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have spent the last week trying to get my TFS Branch / VSO / Azure Release Branch Continous Deployment setup, but have failed miserably. Right now I am just trying to get CD working with out branching, I have it pointed at my solution but I am falling over myself on the obj and bin folder. If I exclude the bin folder from the project it complains because it cant build the project. I can't get tfignore to work, if I change the folder it still tracks the changes.

I have a folder structure of:

```
\Dev\Web\Umbraco Master Solution\Umbraco.Extensions\bin
\Dev\Web\Umbraco Master Solution\Umbraco.Extensions\obj
\Dev\Web\.tfignore
```

my tfignore includes the lines:

```
\Umbraco Master Solution\Umbraco.Extensions\bin
\Umbraco Master Solution\Umbraco.Extensions\obj
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: Side Question: Is it normal to check in your bin folder? How do Azure CD work with out it?

Comment: I've verified with out the dlls from the bin folder, the build will fail on deployment on checkin. So I need to have the bin folder and dlls in tfs.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost always a bad idea to checkin your bin folder.  If the build fails when  you exclude it, that likely means you have a DLL that is referenced from the bin (also not good).  You should use Nuget packages where possible for your dependencies.  Its easy to make your own if needed.  Or you can place the DLLs you need to reference in a different folder at the root of your solution and referenced those instead.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a piece, I can build it locally, but as part of the deployment process, the build in My Builds in Team Explorer fails. Not sure if that changes your answer at all.

Comment: The answer still applies. It works locally because you have all the files.  If you don't checkin the bin folder and have referenced a DLL from the bin folder then the build fails on the build server. Review the properties of each referenced DLL (ignore project references) and check the path to make sure none are in the bin folder.  You can right click on the assemblies reference and choose Properties.  Move any assemblies that are referenced in the bin folder to a new "lib" (the name doesn't matter) folder at the root and update the assemblies reference to point there.  Checkin the lib folder.

Comment: I'm confused, I have been using nuget, aren't all the dlls in the bin folder stored there because of nuget?

Also I don't get the reasoning of why its better to move them to another location and give it a different name, how is that any better?

Comment: My problem went away when I included the bin in the project (still being deployed) and excluded the obj folder from the project. But I am still interested in your answers to my previous questions.

Comment: 'bin' is intended to be the output of the build process.  You should be able to delete it and rebuild to fill it again.  Nuget packages (including the packaged dlls) are stored in the [solution root]\packages folder.  I'm only suggesting moving dlls not part of Nuget packages to another folder.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/90014dd0-f0c8-4bce-826b-3cdfbdce0679/visual-studio-online-hosted-build-agent-why-is-objdebug-not-created-andor-not-accessible?forum=tfsadmin

A link to a similar issue

Comment: And this one 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b214b218-e3d8-463b-b627-a814507a6ac8/visual-studio-online-hosted-build-agent-why-is-objdebug-not-created-andor-not-accessible?forum=tfsadmin

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you would like to check-in the Bin of the project you are referencing.  when you set up your build, you have to select a configuration to build.  Make sure that the configuration you are building has the project you are referencing set to Build.

I agree with chief7 that it's a bad idea to check in your bin folder.